# Rest services always returning Error 401 with Postman but integration test are working

Tags: java, spring-security

I have a simple springboot application (2.1.7.RELEASE) exposing 2 rest services and I can consume them with Postman or Curl. (I don't have any front-end app).
Now, I want to apply spring-security step by step.
The first one is just to apply the security, set permissions to give access to everyone to a specific route and restrict the other one. 
My code is working fine when I run my integration tests but I receive a 401 error when I try to consume them from Postman or Curl.

I already tried to change the permission in the WebSecurityConfiguration like this

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
```

but I always received the 401 error.

My application is this one

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootConsoleApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootConsoleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

with 2 rest services in my Rest Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/character")
public class CharacterController {

    @GetMapping("/{characterId}")
    public ResponseEntity<CharacterDto> getCharacterById(@PathVariable("characterId") UUID characterId){
        CharacterDto character = createCharacterDto();
        character.setUuid(characterId);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(character, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/name/{surname}")
    public ResponseEntity<CharacterDto> getCharacterByName(
            @PathVariable("surname") String surname){
        CharacterDto character = createCharacterDto();
        character.setName(surname);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(character, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    private CharacterDto createCharacterDto() {
        return CharacterDto.builder()
                .uuid(UUID.randomUUID())
                .name("Yandar Toramun")
                .race("Human")
                .cclass("Cleric")
                .charisma(12)
                .constitution(12)
                .dexterity(10)
                .intelligence(9)
                .strength(13)
                .wisdom(16)
                .build();
    }
}
```

with security enabled

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers("/api/v1/character/*").denyAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/v1/character/name/*").permitAll()
                .and().anonymous()
                ;

    }
}
```

In this specific scenario, I want that everyone (non connected user) get a character by name but character by id is not authorized.

I have 2 tests:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {SpringBootConsoleApplication.class, CharacterController.class,WebSecurityConfiguration.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Log4j2
class CharacterControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void getCharacterById() throws Exception {
        log.debug("getCharacterById: ");
        MvcResult result = mockMvc
                .perform(
                        get(
                "/api/v1/character/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString()
                        )
                .accept("application/json")).andExpect(status().is4xxClientError()).andReturn();
        log.debug(result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
    }
    @Test
    public void getCharacterByName() throws Exception {
        log.debug("getCharacterByName: ");
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get(
                "/api/v1/character/name/KalEl")
                .accept("application/json")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();
        log.debug(result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
    }

}
```

Those tests succeed.

But when I try with curl or with postman, I always receive an error 401.

As describe in my test, I would like to receive a http status 200 on /api/v1/character/name/xxxxx and an error 401 on /api/v1/character/uuid

Where is my mistake?

**UPDATE**
By adding the scanBasPackageClasses with the config classes, it is working fine now.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = {CharacterController.class, WebSecurityConfiguration.class})
```

I tought that these Beans was automatically scanned when we used the annotations. 
Finally, it was due to my project structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The security configuration is not taken into account because the package it belongs to is not scanned. That means that security is auto configured and requires authentication. On top of the `SpringBootConsoleApplication` class try:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "org.jonleb.examples")
```

and it should work. I don't know why spring boot can find the controller but not the security config without the above. You try starting in debug mode and go through Spring's output.

On a side note, I suggest this equivalent security configuration:

```
http
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/api/v1/character/*").denyAll()
    .antMatchers("/api/v1/character/name/*").permitAll();
```

1. You should disable csrf if you are not using it
2. You shouldn't repeat `authorizeRequests()`. Not needed and may cause problems.
3. `anonymous()` doesn't seem to do anything useful. May cause problems.
4. I haven't seen mixing of `antMatchers` and `mvcMatchers` before. May cause problems but probably not.

Also when testing `/api/v1/character/name/*` or any endpoint you configured with `permitAll()` with curl or postman do NOT pass an `Authorization` header.

Finally if you want to permit all endpoints except some, just add the ones you want to deny and add `.anyRequest().permitAll()` at the end.

Comment: I try but I still have the issue. Integration tests succeed as expected but curl or postman failed on /api/v1/character/name/*
thx

Comment: Can you post the curl command you are using and the full response?

Comment: ` curl -v http://localhost:8080/api/v1/character/name/myname`
full response is here: https://pastebin.com/VDvdAgxh
Thx

Comment: I'm wondering if it is due to the WebSecurityConfiguration or if it is a general issue with the configuration. I don't understand why it is working as expected with the integration test and it is nor working with curl or postman.

Comment: integration test and it is nor working with curl or postman.
Even with this config: http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
I have the result.

Comment: Right. I quickly copied and pasted the above source code in project created with Spring Initialzr and the curl request above works fine. But if hit `localhost:8080/api/v1/character/myname` I get 403. You get a 401 and a mention of Basic Authentication in your response. Can you confirm you haven't activated Basic Auth e.g. by calling `httpBasic()` or something like `security.basic.enabled=true`at your `application.properties`

Comment: I don't have anything in my code (which is avalaible on https://github.com/jonleb/TemplateSpringBoot/tree/open-id-support) related to httpbasic. 
But you are right, when I open localhost:8080/api/v1/character/name in the browser, I'm redirected to a login page. I don't understand why. Thx

Comment: In my logfile, I have this message:
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter: Access is denied (user is anonymous); **redirecting to authentication entry point**.

Comment: It seems you found the problem yourself! Hadn't seen your edit while editing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ant matchers are processed in order, like if statements.

So, declaring them as

```
.antMatchers("/").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/a/**").denyAll()
.antMatchers("/a/b/**").permitAll()
```

Is the same as doing

```
if ( path matches "/" ) {
    // allow
} else if ( path matches "/a/**" ) {
    // deny
} else if ( path matches "/a/b/***" ) {
    // allow
}
```

Because `"/a/b/**"` matches the `"/a/**"` condition, that one is checked first and the request is denied.

This is similar to how catch blocks work, for another analogy.

The solution is to list your narrower matches first:

```
.antMatchers("/").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/a/b/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/a/**").denyAll()
```

Comment: I tried the following code: 
`http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll().antMatchers("/api/v1/character/name/**").permitAll().antMatchers("/api/v1/character/**").denyAll();` and the result is exactly the same (integration tests succeed and postman give 401 error)

Comment: That was my first thought. I noticed he is using one wildcard (*) at the end so `/api/v1/character/*` shouldn't match `/api/v1/character/name/*`. But your suggestion is good practice nevertheless.